# Digitally Sign a UWP Standalone App Package

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, signing

I made an open source UWP app which I want publish in my website. I don't want to publish it the store. I want to make my app a standalone package with digitally signed certificate. How do I digitally sign the UWP app.

I've created a .pfx certificate in visual studio and installed it. But even that won't work. Please Suggest me a correct way of signing a standalone app without releasing it to store...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish your app for sideloading, you will want to create a certificate (.cer file) that you can install on a machine that you intend to run your app on; without it you cannot install the application. when you publish, and choose to create the file, it will be placed in the AppPackages folder along with your installer and any Dependencies your program needs.

When *first* installing your package, it's recommended to install via the powershell script provided as it will take care of installing these additional dependencies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps

In order to install the application on a machine, the machine must have that certificate installed in the correct manner prior to running the installer (MSIX file). Those key points:

1. Installed for the local machine
2. Browsing to determine how to place the certificate
3. Installing it for Trusted People

Comment: "you will want to create a certificate (.cer file) that you can install on a machine that you intend to run your app on" - wouldn't a widely-trusted Authenticode certificate also work?

Comment: I am not sure...I do know that visual studio has built in functionality to create the accompanying certificate though and meets the requirement of allowing install of a sideloaded UWP app.

Comment: Visual Studio has functionality to create certificates. When you publish an app, It'll be automatically asked...